# Selenium(Java) : click() is not clicking the button,it is just selecting.Any other way?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Selenium webdriver using click() is not clicking the button "upload File". I am able to identify the button using xpath but some how unable to click it. Is there any other method to do so?

Comment: Not enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: <input id="button-option-222" class="button " type="button" value="Upload File">

Comment: Please let me know if you need full page source or any other details.

Comment: When I spy using firebug, I see the button can be accessed from two tags. 1)<div id="option-222" class="option">
<span class="required">*</span>
<b>File:</b>
<br>
<input id="button-option-222" class="button " type="button" value="Upload File">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="option[222]">
</div>                                                               2)<input type="file" name="file" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 480px; cursor: pointer;">.From second tag I am unable to select using xpath, so I don't understand why this is happening .

Comment: But sometimes it works, right? Very odd problem in selenium since some time :(

Comment: click() is working fine in all cases except this one ,the page may have been designed in a peculiar way.I was able to get a work around in this case, but not sure why Webdriver did not click the button when xpath is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uploading file use sendKeys, in sendkeys send your file path

Ex:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//myxpath")).sendKeys("C:\\drive\\NewTextDocument.txt");
```

Comment: I don't find a input box, it see a button. Thanks!

Comment: If you are not using any frameworks like Extjs, jquery ui, then above code will work. In latest version of firefox and chrome they show only button for file uploading. Try the above code if not working post your html code of your file upload button.

Comment: yes, I have tried it, it did not work. html code of the button :<input id="button-option-222" class="button " type="button" value="Upload File">

Comment: the above code works for input of type file, and sample html code looks like <input type="file">, seems you have a front end framework used where custom events are fired

Comment: It Worked ! Thanks! . I used the 2nd xpath(as I mentioned in the description notes). That has type as file.